# Update permissions on folder to let user scp file there?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I have a folder named "webapps" with the following permissions:

```
$ ls -al /opt/tomcat
$ drwxr-x--- 7 tomcat root    4096 Aug 15 22:06 webapps
```

I have a user which is part of the "tomcat" group:

```
$ groups
$ hamburgers sudo tomcat
```

When I try to scp a file from my local machine to the /webapps folder on my server, I get a permission denied error:

```
scp -r /mymachine/test.war hamburgers@123.123.123.123:"/opt/tomcat/webapps/test.war"
scp: /opt/tomcat/webapps/test.war: Permission denied
```

I thought since user "hamburgers" was part of the "tomcat" group, they'd be able to do this. I can scp the same way to other folders on the server.

How could I change the permissions to get this to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment the group owner is root, not tomcat, so being in the tomcat group won't help hamburgers.

Change the group ownership to the tomcat group

```
sudo chown -R :tomcat /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

The `-R` makes `chown` apply recursively to all the contents of the directory.

The group will need write permission too:

```
sudo chmod g+w /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

Or if you prefer octal :)

```
sudo chmod 770 /opt/tomcat/webapps
```